# How to use Response of one In another method typescript without ID value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

from the service response, need to get that in ngOnit function of another component but don't have **ids** in that typescript

Here **ids** means

```
detailvisit(visit: Visit) {
     const ids = {
      'ID': visit.ID,
      'patientid': visit.pid,
    };
    this.visitService.getavisit(ids);
    this.router.navigate(['/detailvisit']);
  }
```

Service for get a record

```
getavisit(ids): Observable<Visit> {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token });
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers });
  return this.http.post('/api/getvisit/', JSON.stringify(ids), options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
                   return <Visit>response.json();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .subscribe and place the router.navigate inside that

```
this.visitService.getavisit(ids).subscribe( response => {
                     console.log("Success Response" + token)
                     this.router.navigate(['/detailvisit']);
                   },
 error =>  console.log(error));
```